# Nativescript-vue GridLayout row alignment

Tags: nativescript-vue

I am lacking in any sort of UI/X skills, and am really struggling with alignment of my page.  In particular, I am trying to build a grid that resembles Excel - rows and columns of data from a list.  I can get the rows, but all the data are cramped together.

```
 <ListView for="item in personList" class="list-group" height="200">
     <v-template>
         <GridLayout columns="auto, auto, auto, auto" rows="*" class="list-group-item">
             <Label col="0" :text="item.date" class="list-group-item-text" ></Label>
             <Label col="1" :text="item.firstName" class="list-group-item-text" ></Label>
             <Label col="2" :text="item.lastName"  class="list-group-item-text" ></Label>
             <Label col="3" :text="item.address.zip"  class="list-group-item-text"  style="align:right"></Label>
       </GridLayout>
    </v-template>
 </ListView>
```

When the page is shown, all the text appears as one long string.  I have been unable to get each of the labels to appear as a distinct cell, ideally with padding to separate them.  I tried setting the horizonalAlighnment="right", padding, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting column width to `auto`, it spans enough to show the text inside. Instead, you might want to have at least one of them stretch as much the container width allows.

Using `*` the column takes the maximum space available, as in [the docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/layouts/layout-containers#gridlayout).
Ex. `columns="* * * *"` to split the layout in 4 same sized columns.

Comment: Thank you, this works a lot better `<GridLayout columns="100, 75, 75, 300" class="list-group-item">` . Is there anyway to make those percentages, since I don't know the screen size of all the devices?  Also, the right align for the one column doesn't seem to be effected by `horizonalAlighnment="right"`

Comment: Is the width of your grid fixed or does it stretch across all the screen/container?

Comment: It stretches across the width of the screen.  I set the grid height to 100 because it has a StackLayout above and beneath and its the only way I could get it to display.

Comment: Then you could treat `*` as percentages.
For example:
`*, *, *, *` => 100% / 4 = 25% for each star.
`2*, 2*, *, *` => 100% / (2+2+1+1) = 16,6% for each star. The first two take two stars, so your columns will be 33,3%, 33,3%, 16,6%, 16,6%.
And so on, all documented in the docs.

Also, if you're having trouble with vertical spacing and aren't using a ScrollView, you could consider using a GridLayout with the same strategy.

Comment: Thank you, that makes much more sense than the documentation and your example gave me a great direction to follow. I am currently using FlexBoxLayout for vertical but I will try to use the GridLayout instead since Flex doesn't seem to do what I want.